# Problem trying to pass props to child component

Tags: reactjs

I´m making my first project with React and everything is working fine but one simple thing... but I don´t know what I´m missing and I think I tried everything.

I´m trying to pass some props/info to a child component like this but it seems it´s not receiving any info. What am I missing here? That console.log in the child component is throwing an empty object whatever I try to do.

In my main App.jsx I have this code:

`<Popup miData={{title:'Hello world', text:'Lorem ipsum...'}}/>`

and that child component is something like:

```
import React from "react"
const Popup = (miData) => {
   console.log(miData)
    return (
        html code here is fine, component is being rendered correctly
    )
}
export default Popup
```

(both components are being rendered fine, everything works fine but this passing props thing)

Comment: So what is logged to the console?

Comment: an empty object

Comment: also share the snippet where you are passing the props in popup

Comment: rename it to myData when passing in props

Comment: That was a typo posting here, it´s called "miData" in both parent and child components. Just edited my question, my bad.

Comment: The only reason that could happen is if you have two `<Popup />` components and you render the one that don't have props passed

Comment: try changing ```const Popup = (myData) => {``` to ```const Popup = ({myData}) => {```

Comment: I tried that before and then I get undefined.


@Konrad just double checked, I have just one and actually getting the error just once, otherwise i should have it twice.

Comment: @Pizzaboy error?

Comment: I mean the undefined/empty object, not a proper error @Konrad

Comment: Works fine on sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-maxwell-htzgve?file=/src/App.js

Comment: But not showing any of the info passed in miData, right? I mean, if I try to add miData.title within the html code, nothing renders, it´s still empty

Comment: @Pizzaboy you do understand that `miData` is the object consisting of the props as its properties, right?

Comment: Of course I do, and I guess you´ll understand and empty object doesn´t have any properties.

Comment: @Pizzaboy please try reproducing your issue on codesandbox or any other platform. Or maybe give us a link you your repository

Comment: Already fixed with last @HarshGupta answer, ty everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding react Fragments in your return statement

```
import React from "react"
const Popup = (miData) => {
   console.log(miData);
    return (
      <>
        html code here is fine, component is being rendered correctly
      </>
    );
}
export default Popup;
```

Its working for me on my sandbox

Comment: I´m returning the code within <> code </>

You mean that, right? (I´m sorry total noob here)

Comment: did it work for you? Is the problem solved? @Pizzaboy

Comment: It didn´t, I´m starting to think the problem is not the code... both Konrad and you saying code should be working but it´s not. I don´t know if I´m doing something wrong besides this

Comment: share a screenShot of your console where you are getting empty object And have you now applied the fragments?

Comment: https://ibb.co/CnsL7L7

Comment: just once also share the screenShot where you are passing the props

Comment: https://ibb.co/G2VtGZ2